# How to zoom within distance by giving location?

Tags: iphone

I am trying zoom MKMapView by giving location. Also it would be looking around X meters from the location.

How to make it ?

I tried following code :

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude     = longitude;
region.center.longitude    = latitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.1;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
[mapView setRegion:region];
```

But no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your code - map doesn't change its region or the delta is incorrect?

Comment: Centered with the location. But it is looking like several zoomed out.  
Actually I don't know how many meters region.span.latitudeDelta and region.span.longitudeDelta equal to ?

For example: 0.1 span equeals to ....

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this article: [Set the Zoom Level of an MKMapView](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/)

Full explanation: [MKMapView and Zoom Levels: A Visual Guide](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/)